# При появлении клавиатуры список не опускается(android)

Tags: android, xml

Когда я нажимаю на поле `summgrn` появляется клавиатура, но вместе со своим появление она закрывает все элементы, а должна поднимать все к верху. Что б пользователь не свайпил вниз для того что бы написать в `summgrn` количество.

До того как пользователь нажал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В манифесте стоит: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fone"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView21"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="1) Введите сумму вашего счета"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="2) Сгенерируйте код"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="3) Покажите код официанту"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="4) Получите бонус на счет"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="258dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="бонусы "
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView7"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:text="Введите сумму"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" >
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_get_bonus"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/summgrn"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:hint="1200"
                                    android:inputType="number"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:maxLength="5"
                                     android:background="@null"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textColorHint="#91623f" >

                                    <requestFocus />
                                </EditText>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="грн."
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="и покажите код официанту"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/generateBonus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#9a5f35"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Получить"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно проскролить `ScrollView` до самого конца

```
scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: назначил `onClickListener` на свой `EditText` и написал что при клике `scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` но в итоге ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 3):

Вашу проблему можно решить через файл manifest. В теге вашей активити добавьте следующий атрибут:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

**adjustPan** - подвинет область контента вверх,
**adjustResize** - уменьшит высоту контента.

Comment: в манифесте написал как вы говорили `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

Вот получилось вот так:

```
  MyEditText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    isKeyboardShown(MyEditText.getRootView());
                }
            });

    //code


    private boolean isKeyboardShown(View rootView) {
            /* 128dp = 32dp * 4, minimum button height 32dp and generic 4 rows soft keyboard */
            final int SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD = 128;

            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            DisplayMetrics dm = rootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            /* heightDiff = rootView height - status bar height (r.top) - visible frame height (r.bottom - r.top) */
            int heightDiff = rootView.getBottom() - r.bottom;
            /* Threshold size: dp to pixels, multiply with display density */
            boolean isKeyboardShown = heightDiff > SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD * dm.density;

            Log.e( "isKeyboardShown ? " + isKeyboardShown + ", heightDiff:" + heightDiff + ", density:" + dm.density
                    + "root view height:" + rootView.getHeight() + ", rect:" + r, "sd");

            if(isKeyboardShown) {
//scrollView1 это мой скрол
                scrollView1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }

            return isKeyboardShown;
        }
```